# Redirect iso-88591-1 url to utf-8 url with nginx

Tags: nginx

We have just switched our site content from iso-8859-1 to utf-8 - this was not a problem. However, we also had iso-8859-1 in our previous urls. Now we have replaced our urls with new urls that contains utf8 instead.

The problem is that we really want our old urls to work also.

Is it possible in nginx to redirect all urls that contain iso-8859-1 to the utf8 equivalent url?

Example:

```
Old url: https://www.example.com/author/Arne%20Sj%F6berg.html
New url: https://www.example.com/author/Arne%20Sj%C3%B6berg.html
```

Comment: The problem is ambiguity. A URI containing `%C3%B6`, could be a single UTF-8 character or two valid iso-88591-1 characters. Nginx has no way to decide which is which.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But my problem is the other way. I want to redirect urls that contain %F6. So it should be possible to detect that if it is only a single iso-8859-1 character, then redirect to UTF8. Right?

If it is not possible to solve in nginx, is there another solution that you can think of?

Answer (score 0):

If `%F6` is the only iso-8859-1 character than needs translating, there's a good chance that it doesn't overlap with your new URIs (yet).

You can apply a regular expression to the `$request_uri` variable which contains the original percent encoded characters.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ "^(.*)%F6(.*)$") { 
    return 301 $1%C3%B6$2;
}
```